# how to make virtual box use video memory from NVIDIA graphics card?

Tags: virtualbox

[image: virtual box screenshot]

as you can see virtual box is using **Video Memory** from Intel HD graphics.
How do I make it use memory from my Nvidia graphics card which has 2Gb memory much bigger than Intel's 128Mb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox is using a virtualised video card and not any of the physical video cards in your machine. In order to give a virtual machine access to physical hardware, you must pass the hardware to the virtual machine. Passing through PCI devices can be difficult and video cards is even more problematic. On top of that, the NVidia proprietary drivers actively attempt to make passing through their cheaper cards more difficult. I am not sure of the state of VGA passthrough in VirtualBox, but you might be better off switching to Xen or KVM where passthrough is more developed.

Answer (score 1):

[Linux Kernel version 4.10 may make it possible for virtual box to use your GPU directly](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3174088/linux/3-little-things-in-linux-410-that-will-make-a-big-difference.html)

> One class of hardware that’s always been difficult to emulate in
>   virtual machines is GPUs. Typically, VMs provide their own custom
>   video driver (slow), and graphics calls have to be translated (slow)
>   back and forth between guest and host. The ideal solution would be to
>   run the same graphics driver in a guest that you use on the host
>   itself and have all the needed calls simply relayed back to the GPU.
>
> There’s more here than being able to play, say, Battlefield 1 in a VM.
>   Every resource provided by the GPU, including GPU-accelerated
>   processing provided through libraries like CUDA, would be available to
>   the VM as if it were running on regular, unvirtualized iron.